# perforce forbid adding to overlay

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

Couple of questions on p4 overlay mappings.

If one has an overlay client view:

```
  //depot/dir1/...  //ws/build/...
  +//depot/dir2/... //ws/build/...
```

1. Is it possible to forbid files to be added to `//depot/dir2` ?
2. How does one specify if the target of a `p4 add` command is `//depot/dir1` or `//depot/dir2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an overlay causes multiple depot paths to map one client path, the default for a `p4 add` (in client syntax) is the last mapping.  If you specify a depot path, that path is used:

```
C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 where ...
//depot/dir1/... //classic/... c:\Perforce\test\depot\...
+//depot/dir2/... //classic/... c:\Perforce\test\depot\...

C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 add -n foo
//depot/dir2/foo#1 - opened for add

C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 add -n //depot/dir1/foo
//depot/dir1/foo#1 - opened for add
```

So just flipping the order of your mapping lines may give you the effect you want (e.g. you can make `dir1` the default by specifying it last in the mapping).  It will still be possible to add files to `dir2` explicitly but it's not likely to happen by accident.

If you want to specify in the client that `dir2` is a read-only path and you *can't* add files to it, the `ChangeView` can be used for that (since anything you map in a ChangeView is automatically made read-only):

```
C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 client -o | tail -n3
ChangeView:
        //depot/dir2/...@now


C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 add -n //depot/dir2/foo
//classic/foo - can't add file that is restricted by client's ChangeView mapping

C:\Perforce\test\depot>p4 add -n //depot/dir1/foo
//depot/dir1/foo#1 - opened for add
```

In this example I'm using `@now` as the revision for the `ChangeView` because I don't actually want to restrict the versions; I just want the side-effect of the path being restricted to read-only operations.

Another way to make a path read-only is to remove `write` permission via `p4 protect`; that would be the better solution if you want to make this a global policy for all users.

Comment: Thanks, somehow couldn't find this through a google search. I've swapped the order of view lines already, but keep hitting a "Null directory (//) not allowed in my ChangeView spec.  What's the syntax when one needs quotes around a path that contains blanks?

Comment: And the answer may be no quotes needed

Comment: yup, no quotes needed in a `ChangeView` entry since it's only a single path (i.e. spaces have no special meaning in parsing it, so no need to quote them).  If you add quotes unnecessarily they'll be interpreted as part of the literal depot path, which gives you an invalid depot path.  :P

Comment: I now have the original order i.e.  dir1 + dir2, and p4 complains that the file is restricted to both dir1 and dir2 paths! (Also, I'm not sure whether the p4v popup with choices of dir1/dir2 is in spec order,,as in a quick test, dir2 always came up first, but I'd rather have ChangeView working. p4 protect probably is not a choice for non-admin users)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "restricted to both paths".  I'd recommend following the example I gave from the command line and making sure you can get that working, and then tackle configuring P4V as a separate problem...

Comment: It means that p4 add -n ../dir1  or p4 add -n ../dir2 both fail as restricted.  I've tried both a simple case and a complicated case (deeper path components, paths with blanks, etc) against my free P4D/NTX64/2018.1/1637071 server and it works, but it fails against my company's licensed P4D/NTX64/2016.1/1396108 server.

Comment: An upgrade should fix it. 
 Here's the bug: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/user/relnotes.txt:

Bugs fixed in 2016.1 Patch 11 

 #1451895 (Bug #88792) **
     A changeview entry in depot syntax which matches a mapping in the
     client's view that is involved an overlay mapping would match all
     depot paths that share the same client path. This has been fixed.

Comment: We're due for an upgrade over the Thanksgiving break.  I'll have to wait till then. Thanks.